# Refactoring in Xcode -- limit to only select files and folders

Tags: xcode, refactoring

When I go to refactor->Rename a var/function/class the default behavior is to search through all of whats in my workspace.  I have my project and a pods project which has ten's of thousands of lines of code.  If I'm changing self.subriberlst to self.subscriberList because I made a type I don't want to search every imported cocoapod library and/or apple framework or whatever else I  have lying around.  Besides taking incredibly long to process the long list of files, Xcode normally just crashes when I do this.  Is there a way to restrict the jurisdiction of the refactoring in xcode such that I only search through perhaps just my project, or even just the file?

Comment: I just use find and replace, there you can limit the scope.

Answer (score 0):

To rename something local, use Xcode's "Edit All in Scope." But that won't go across files.

AppCode is much better at automated refactoring than Xcode. See if it works for you. (It may not, if the workspace is too large.)

Otherwise, do it the tried-and-true way: manual refactoring. For Rename Method, follow the steps described in the [Refactoring book](https://qualitycoding.org/refactoring-book/). Careful manual refactoring involves establishing a new method with the new name before removing the old method.

Whether automated or manual, refactoring should be verified by unit tests. Otherwise, the fallback is to "Lean on the Compiler" then verify with some manual tests.